# Why does adding refrigerant increase subcooling and decrease superheat?

Tags: hvac

Please correct my following notion of why adding refrigerant increases subcooling and decreases superheat:

Let's assume a hypothetical situation:

- condensation point of uncompressed refrigerant (vapor line): 10 degrees
- condensation point of compressed refrigerant (liquid line): 150 degrees degrees
- temperature of vapor entering compressor: 20 degrees (10 degrees superheat)
- temperature of vapor leaving compressor: 180 degrees (30 degrees superheat)
- temperature of liquid leaving outdoor coil: 120 degrees (30 degrees subcooling)
- temperature of liquid leaving metering device: -20 degrees (30 degrees subcooling)

If I add refrigerant to the system the overall system pressure (and thus condensation point) is going to go up, leading to the new situation afterwards:

- condensation point of uncompressed refrigerant (vapor line): 15 degrees
- condensation point of compressed refrigerant (liquid line): 155 degrees degrees
- temperature of vapor entering compressor: 20 degrees (5 degrees superheat)
- temperature of vapor leaving compressor: 180 degrees (25 degrees superheat)
- temperature of liquid leaving outdoor coil: 120 degrees (35 degrees subcooling)
- temperature of liquid leaving metering device: -20 degrees (35 degrees subcooling)

Note how the actual temperatures have not changed but the amount of subcooling/superheat has changed because the two condensation points have changed. This is why adding refrigerant increases subcooling and decreases superheat. At least that's how it works in my mind.
Anyone who actually understands this stuff who's willing to confirm/correct?

Comment: The temps may not have changed because of active devices like a txv. the valves throttle the amount of refrigerant based on temp and if the system is a little low on superheat or the spread of sub cooling way off add to lower superheat.  the active devices can make it more confusing. Left as a comment since most hvac requires a license so it’s not really diy and these questions are usually closed.  Most online hvac chats only allow pro’s for this reason. The easy way to think of it With more refrigerant in the system it takes less energy to achieve pressure so less heat = cooler suction

Comment: Jim not really because once compressed then cooled it is regulated by an orifice or throttle valve the difference in pressure 30-75 n the low side and 150-300 on the high side it varies with temp and type of refrigerant but the amount of work needed to compress it creates more heat when low and shorter cycles through the system is where the difference really is. Remember just changing the temp will change the pressure based on the type of refrigerant.

Comment: Deleted my other comment. Why is the OP positing that the temp of the vapor entering the compressor is 20 degF? And why is he positing that the temp of the liquid leaving the condensing unit is 120 degF? The former seems lower than it could be and the latter too high unless the ambient temp was 110 F or higher.

Comment: And why is the OP positing -20 F for the temp of the liquid leaving the metering device?

Comment: Oh, all the numbers are just for the sake of the example :-) . I was just trying to make a point about subcooling and superheating. I know that your indoor unit will freeze up if the refrigerant is less than 32 degrees and that the compressed vapor doesn't have to be this hot. Just for the sake of argument...